# How to use current tag on a nav menu when the header is a php insert?

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

I am building a website.

I have built a website. For each page, the header and footer are being included as a php include. In the past, before i decided to use insert, i would simply add `class='current'`. However, as its an include I cant just do that because that same bit of code is used for all pages and if i put current class on home link for example, then even when your on the about us page the home link will have the current class. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `header.php` file add a function to check which page is the current page and
then , update your `menu code` so it will have a condition like:

```
<a href='?page=about' <?php if($current_page == 'about') echo "class='current'"; ?>>About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can go about that:

Each page:

```
$current_page_id = 'about';

include "nav.php";
```

Include file:

```
$nav_items = array(

  'home' => array(

    'href' => "/",

    'label' => "Home Page"

  ),
  // home


  'about' => array(

    'href' => "/about",

    'label' => "About"

  ),
  // about

  ...

);
// $nav_items


?>

<ul>

<?php

foreach ( $nav_items as $nav_id => $nav_item ) {

  $nav_item[ 'class' ] = $nav_id === $current_page_id ? 'active' : '';

  echo <<<DOCHERE

<li>
<a class="{$nav_item[ 'class' ]}" href="{$nav_item[ 'href' ]}">{$nav_item[ 'label' ]}</a>
</li>

DOCHERE;

?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also give an id to your body, indicating on wich page you are. Something like this:

```
<body id="home-page">
...
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="home-button">home</li>
  <li id="about-button">about us</li>
  ...
</ul>
...
```

Then in your css you could do something like this

```
#nav li {
   /* the default styling */
}
#home-page #home-button, about-page #about-button, ... {
   /* the 'active' styling */
}
```

Plenty of possibilities!